# Windows 10 UWP targeting windows 10 mobile only

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile

Is it possible to target a uwp app just for Windows 10 mobile? I mean can we configure in the manifest just to work with phone and not tablet or desktop? Also, the users should not be able to search for the app on the store from a tablet, desktop etc but only from a phone.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an entry in `Package.appxmanifest` specifying, which device families your application targets. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be exposed in the editor, therefore you'll need to edit the XML directly. This is the entry, you need to change:

```
<Dependencies>
  <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
</Dependencies>
```

Replace `Windows.Universal` with `Windows.Mobile`. Check the [reference documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn986903.aspx) for more information.

Also, when you are preparing the submission for the store, you can select which device families you want your application to be available for:

[image: Windows 10 device family selection in store]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the MSDN [guide page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx#device_families), this is quoted directly from there.

> You may not want your app to run on a wide range of devices; perhaps it's specialized for, say, a desktop PC or for an Xbox console. In that case you can choose to target your app at one of the child device families. For example, if you target the desktop device family, the APIs guaranteed to be available to your app include the APIs inherited from the universal device family plus the APIs that are particular to the desktop device family.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the interesting things about UWP.  We have the option to target tons of devices (phones, tablets, desktops, Xbox, and HoloLense) with the same code base.  This is a big sell if you are currently deciding whether to build for Windows 10 vs other platforms.  However, yes, you can decide if you only want a certain application to be on mobile (although the term mobile is now so ambiguous) or desktop.